# Error while consuming WCF from class library from an application deployed on IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, iis

I am new to WCF services and getting an Error while consuming WCF from Class library, pls correct if i wrong somewhere; I m explaining my problem in steps

1.separate WCF project that is deployed in local IIS, running well from Visual studio(dev env).

2.created `CustomClientChannelFactory` class and consuming WCF from Business Layer(ie class library)

```
CustomClientChannelFactory<IPDServices.IIPDServices> objChannelFactory = new CustomClientChannelFactory<IPDServices.IIPDServices>("BasicHttpBinding_IIPDServices", "HISWCFService.config"); 
                IPDServices.IIPDServices obj = objChannelFactory.CreateChannel();    
                strXML = obj.GetAllAdmittedPatients(strHospitalId);
```

1. binding information stored in `HISWCFService.config` (renamed App.config) and copied in 
   specified location (`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0`), this is working well on local VS WebDev server while debugging app.
2. problem started when i deployed App in IIS getting an Error 
   "`The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null. The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.`"

Please suggest

Comment: Did you try to copt your cobfiguration to web.config?

Comment: yes, I did, but then i require to write something like = new CustomClientChannelFactory<IPDServices.IIPDServices>("BasicHttpBinding_IIPDServices", "web.config");  IT IS NOT READING from web.config

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your client config file

Comment: I found solution by writing `Configuration configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

            ServiceModelSectionGroup group = 
    ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(configuration);`